# I just want to swap two numbers using C. But I am not getting the desired output

Tags: c

Below is my code which should swap the numbers entered by the user:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    double Num1,Num2,temp;
    scanf("%.1lf  %.1lf",&Num1,&Num2);
    temp=Num1;
    Num1=Num2;
    Num2=temp;
    printf("%.2lf\n%.2lf",Num1,Num2);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the following output from my code:

```
    1 2
    2.00 1.00
```

but the output which I am getting is:

```
    1 2
    0.00 0.00
```

where do I need to make changes?

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf` and print the numbers before you swap them. Are you sure that's the format string you want to use?

Comment: what is the purpose of `temp=Num1;` and `Num1=Num2;` and `Num2=temp;`?

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. The warnings will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `scanf` format string from `%.1lf  %.1lf` to `%1lf  %1lf` (notice, no dots).

This will read one-digit doubles, which is seemingly what you want.

---

The `.` modifier is not supported by `scanf` in the same way it is supported by `printf` - you must carry out this logic yourself, if you need it.

You can configure your compiler to warn you about these sorts of errors, for instance in gcc:

```
main.c:4:13: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%.1lf  %.1lf",&Num1,&Num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removed the '.' and added some printf to see better the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    double Num1,Num2,temp;
    scanf("%1lf  %1lf",&Num1,&Num2);
    printf("Before swap:");
    printf(" %2lf %2lf\n",Num1,Num2);
    temp=Num1;
    Num1=Num2;
    Num2=temp;
    printf("After swap:");
    printf(" %2lf %2lf\n",Num1,Num2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gabi5537 !!! Your Answer really helped me ☺